# What is technical difference between SubmitChanges in Linq-to-SQL and SaveChanges in Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

What is technical difference between `SubmitChanges` in Linq-to-SQL and `SaveChanges` in Entity Framework?

We know `SubmitChanges` is a concept for `DataContext` class while `SaveChanges` is a method of `ObjectContext`.

Are there any another differences?

Thanks

Comment: It's basically the same thing - just for two different libraries of code. From a functional standpoint: both will persist first determine all changes you have made to a set of data and then save those changes back to the persistant store (the database, typically).

Answer (score 38, accepted):

From MSDN:

**SaveChanges** operates within a transaction. SaveChanges will roll back that transaction and throw an exception if any of the dirty ObjectStateEntry objects cannot be persisted

**SubmitChanges** starts a transaction and will roll back if an exception occurs while SubmitChanges is executing. However, this does not roll back the changes in memory or tracked by the DataContext; those changes will need to be rolled back manually. You can start with a new instance of the DataContext if the changes in memory are to be discarded.

Comment: In short, no difference at all.

Comment: @Marc.2377 I think there is a clear difference. Not sure why you state otherwise.

Comment: Looks like the SaveChanges() is much better. No need to manually roll back in case things happen. Quick and dirty, I guess.

Comment: They both have their pro's and con's. That is why they are both there.