# How can I set up my model to perform this transaction?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity

I have a portion of my database created with

```
/*
   Create table of scores of games played. Every game will have a score recorded, but there
   will only be a corresponding name if the user enters one
*/
CREATE TABLE Scores ( id int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
                      score int NOT NULL,
                      name VARCHAR (50) 
                    );

/* 
    Create table of text logs of the games played. These are reviewed to sniff out cheating.  
*/
CREATE TABLE GameLogs ( id int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
                        scoreId INT NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES scores(id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE, 
                        logText VARCHAR (8000)
                       );
```

and I'm using the model generated by the Entity framework to try and perform the equivalent of the following transaction.

```
 INSERT INTO Scores (score, name) VALUES (someNumber, someString); 
 SELECT MAX(id) as new_id FROM Scores; 
 INSERT INTO GameLogs (scoreId, logText) VALUES (new_id, someOtherString);
```

The corresponding classes that are generated by Entity are

```
public partial class Score
{
    public Score()
    {
        GameLogs = new HashSet<GameLog>();
    }

    public int id { get; set; }

    [Column("score")]
    public int score1 { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    public string name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<GameLog> GameLogs { get; set; }
}
```

---

```
public partial class GameLog
{
    public int id { get; set; }

    public int scoreId { get; set; }

    [StringLength(8000)]
    public string logText { get; set; }

    public virtual Score Score { get; set; }
}
```

---

```
public partial class SnakeDb : DbContext
{
    public SnakeDb()
        // Comment/uncomment the base(...) depending on where project is being deployed at the moment
        // Local Database:
        //: base("name=snakedb")
        // Remove database: 
        : base("name=remote_snakedb")
    {
    }

    public virtual DbSet<BannedIP> BannedIPs { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<GameLog> GameLogs { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<IP> IPs { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Score> Scores { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating ( DbModelBuilder modelBuilder )
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<GameLog>()
            .Property(e => e.logText)
            .IsUnicode(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<IP>()
            .HasMany(e => e.BannedIPs)
            .WithRequired(e => e.IP)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Score>()
            .Property(e => e.name)
            .IsUnicode(false);
    }
}
```

---

In one of my controllers I have the method

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SubmitScore ( NameScoreLog nsp )
    {

        // Submit name and score to Scores database
        SD.Scores.Add( new Score { name = nsp.name, score1 = nsp.score } );

        // ... 

        SD.SubmitChanges();

    }
```

which is where I plan to perform the transaction I mentioned. Right now I am completely clueless about how I am going to extract the `id` from the last element added to `SD.Scores`, i.e. do the equivalent of

```
SELECT MAX(id) as new_id FROM Scores;
```

which, by the way, I realize is a flawed way of getting the `id` the last added score, given that another score could be inserted in between the time that I added my score and made the above query.

Can someone give me some guidance on how to attack this problem?

Comment: It does not answer your question, but you should not be using `SELECT MAX(id)` to get the ID of latest inserted record in SQL. You can select wrong data if you have two operations running at the same time. You should use [`SCOPE_IDENTITY()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx) instead

Comment: is you id auto_incemented?

Comment: @Arvaan Yes, at the database level, but there's nothing in my C# that makes this happen in my model before I submit the changes to the database. Right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This:

```
  var score = new Score { name = nsp.name, score1 = nsp.score };
  SD.Scores.ADD(score);
  db.savechanges();
  var id = score .Id;
```

Comment: Where is the method that sets the `id` when you create a new `Score` element? I don't see it in the implementation of the class `Score` that I posted above, and the class doesn't extend another class, so ...

Comment: is it not autoincrement?

Comment: Can you try this please? if it is working then I will explain you the proper reason

Comment: to test I need to submit the changes to the database, and I'm getting an error ' ... does not contain a definition for SubmitChanges() ...'. You can see here https://github.com/jamkin/Snake/blob/master/SnakeGame/Controllers/PlayController.cs the code that is producing it. I don't know why SubmitChanges is not recognized as a method for SD, but SaveChanges is ...

Comment: no need to do submitchanges. just only savechanges is required

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10980619/what-is-technical-difference-between-submitchanges-in-linq-to-sql-and-savechange you can find solution of your confusion here